# What would be a good tag for questions of the type "Are there languages with XYZ?"

Tags: discussion, tags

We're getting a pretty solid bunch of tags for linguistics concepts, but most SE sites also have tags for kinds of questions which are useful too, especially when we identify the trends.

One trend is "Do languages exist with such and such?" and I think it might be useful to gather them under a tag but I'm not sure what to name it.

[language-features](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-features) possibly, but maybe "feature" has a technical sense which might make it ambiguous or confusing sometimes. Are there some other possibilities?

Comment: I corrected the fake-tags in your question and in the answers. :)

Answer (score 6):

What about [language-by-feature](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-by-feature)?

Comment: +1 it's a good one, better than [tag:cross-linguistic]

Answer (score 2):

We already have [reference-request](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), so how about [language-request](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-request)?  Maybe it isn't the most intuitive name, except by analogy with reference-request, but it describes exactly what these questions are seeking.

Comment: I dunno. You can fulfil a request but you can't fulfil a language (-:

Answer (score 1):

How about [language-lists](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-lists)? Such questions usually ask for a list of languages that satisfy some criteria.

Comment: I think that would make it look like we were encouraging lists of all kinds. Answers to a tag of this sort wouldn't have to be lists anyway. They might include only one example and still be a good answer.

Comment: Alright. I +1'd "language-by-feature". I seem to be too "semantic" in my thinking... and so, for me, a list (set) could have one or even zero items ;-).

Comment: There's always tag synonyms for fixing and adjusting the details later too (-:

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was under the impression that we had a lot of these questions, but now that I look through the questions it seems that even if they are there, a lot of them are asking more about how a specific feature works and are tagged for that feature or an area of study. To me that's more important than grouping by question format (for example, questions about phonology are more closely related than questions that happen to ask "are there other languages with x").

If we do go with grouping these, [cross-linguistic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-linguistic) seems like a good place to start looking for questions that might fit. Regarding possible names:

Resources like [WALS](http://wals.info/) do use the word *features* but more generally call these *properties*, specifically "structural (phonological, grammatical, lexical) properties". In [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests+phrase-requests) we use the term *request* for some of the questions asking to help find a word or find whether a term for something exists. Obviously this isn't a *feature-request* because that sounds like a request for an addition to software, but maybe it's a request to find a language that has a certain property—a *language-property-request*, *cross-linguistic-request*, something like that.

Comment: I have been unsure when to use the [tag:cross-linguistic]. Should it be for questions which specifically cover more than one language, questions which might implicitly cover more than one language, or something technical that I'm unaware of. Would you like to give it a tag wiki?

Comment: The closest tag I've been using to a "request" tag would be [tag:terminology] when I'm asking what term is used to cover a specific phenomenon, but of course it can also be used to ask for clarification of terms you already know and other things.